# dd: почему нельзя просто так взять и поменять значения bs и count местами?

Tags: linux

Создадим парочку файлов с неважно каким содержимым, с размером например 2048 и 115424 байт:

```
$ truncate -s 2048 f1
$ truncate -s 115424 f2
```

Сделаем скрипт, который печатает эти файлы и ещё 12465440 байт из /dev/zero впридачу:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat f1 f2
dd if=/dev/zero bs=12465440 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

Школьные знания арифметики подсказывают нам, что этот скрипт должен вывести 12582912 байт:

```
$ ./script.sh | dd > something
24575+2 записей получено
24576+0 записей отправлено
12582912 байт (13 MB, 12 MiB) скопирован, 0,268635 s, 46,8 MB/s
```

Если мы укажем bs=1 count=12582912, то согласно той же арифметике ничего не изменится:

```
$ ./script.sh | dd bs=1 count=12582912 > something
12582912+0 записей получено
12582912+0 записей отправлено
12582912 байт (13 MB, 12 MiB) скопирован, 36,3194 s, 346 kB/s
```

От перемены мест множителей произведение измениться не должно, но линукс со мной почему-то не согласен:

```
$ ./script.sh | dd bs=12582912 count=1 > something
0+1 записей получено
0+1 записей отправлено
2048 байт (2,0 kB, 2,0 KiB) скопирован, 0,00340212 s, 602 kB/s
```

Если попробовать позапускать эту команду ещё несколько раз, то арифметика начинает окончательно сходить с ума:

```
$ ./script.sh | dd bs=12582912 count=1 > something
0+1 записей получено
0+1 записей отправлено
117472 байт (117 kB, 115 KiB) скопирован, 0,00399192 s, 29,4 MB/s
```

Что происходит? Почему последняя команда не выдаёт 12582912 байт? Каково происхождение загадочных чисел 2048 и 117472?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/797664/whats-the-difference-between-dds-command-options-bs-1024-count-1-and-bs-1-coun

Comment: `Если попробовать позапускать эту команду ещё несколько раз, то арифметика начинает окончательно сходить с ума` - не смог воспроизвести, всегда 2048 байт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Alexander Prokoshev по сути уже все описал в своем ответе (исследовании), поэтому постараюсь описать наблюдаемую картину покороче.

Итак, первый раз, вызывая `dd count=12582912 bs=1`,  вы просите у [dd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) читать из `stdin` (в вашем случае это `pipe`) 12582912 раз (аргумент *`count`*) по 1 байту (аргумент *`bs`*).

Поскольку скрипт, `stdout` которого читает `dd`, был запрограммирован на выдачу 12582912 байт  `dd` успешно прочла все данные.

Во втором случае, вы просите `dd` читать из `stdin` **один раз** 12582912 байт. Однако, системный вызов [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read), который использует `dd` с аргументом ***`bs`***,   устроен так, что при чтении из `pipe` (или другого символьного устройства) он **читает столько байт, сколько в данный момент доступно** (в случае `pipe` это количество байт, которые к моменту вызова `read()` было записано скриптом в `stdout`) (естественно, `read()` никогда не читает больше, чем в нем задано).

Поскольку внутреннее состояние ОС все время разное, вы при разных запусках своего теста получаете разные результаты (т.е. вы измеряете количество байт, которые скрипт успел записать в `stdout` к моменту чтения в `dd`).

P.S.

Использование аргумента *`bs`* (точнее *`ibs`*, *`obs`*) было важно при работе с  *магнитными лентами* (сейчас практически забытыми) из-за их довольно специфичной блочной структуры.

Comment: Таки да, фраза «сколько в данный момент доступно» для меня ключевая, а то я в питоне привык, что питоновский read ждёт, пока не станет доступно ровно указанное число байт (ну или eof). Смог воспроизвести ситуацию в сишном коде и понял)

Comment: не соглашусь по последнему абзацу. BS хоть и не сильно, но влияет при передачах в блочные устройства. записывать большие файлы удобно с блоком в 20 мегабайт в этом случае оптимальней отрабатывает DMA и кеш диска. Также размер блока влияет на скорость передачи данных по tcp

Comment: @eri, безусловно, размер блока влияет на производительность. Что касается bs и чтения ленты, то наверное надо было написать *`"было критически важным"`*, поскольку, читая ленту со стандартным `ibs=512`,  вы теряли все данные блока (если они были больше 512), кроме первых 512 байт. / А какая связь между `dd` и tcp? (или вы имели в виду NFS?)

Comment: @avp я тут как-то диск клонировал через `nc` =) и nfs, cifs, iscsi тоже

Answer (score 3):

Это не то чтобы ответ, скорее, некоторое исследование и приглашение к обсуждению.

На моей системе расклад следующий:

```
f1 2048   bytes
f2 115424 bytes
```

Скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat f1 ff
dd if=/dev/zero bs=12465440 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

Запуск:
`./script |strace -f -o OUT dd bs=12582912 count=1 >something`

Результат — 117472 байта, то есть сумма размеров `f1` и `f2`.
Вывод strace в интересующей части:

`read(0, "o\\\257\201\201;\337W\207\334\345k\343\231I[\f@\207}E\307\362\252\351%\342\317\\\tS\307"..., 12582912) = 117472`

strace «с левой стороны пайпа» показывает, что `dd` при попытке записать файл в stdout получает SIGPIPE, то есть `dd` «на правой стороне» к этому моменту уже завершился.

Выводы:

1. `read()`, заряженный на чтение 12465440 байт, читает по факту меньше, то есть работает в точности так, как написано в мане: «read() attempts to read *up to* count bytes...»
2. `dd` работает в точности как написано в мануале:

   ```
   bs=BYTES
         read and write *up to* BYTES bytes at a time
   ...
   count=N
         copy only N input blocks
   ```

Таким образом, согласно мануалу, нельзя ожидать от `dd`, что он прочтёт точно произведение размера блока на количество блоков байт. Нет. Он прочтёт *не больше* этого произведения, причём, похоже, количество вызовов `read()` будет *равным* параметру `count` (если раньше не встретится конец файла или ошибка), а количество возвращённых каждым `read()`ом байт — *не более* параметра `bs`.

Другое дело, что предсказать размер «блока данных» у меня не получилось. Более того, если ставить strace в самое начало команды или непосредственно справа от пайпа, то на моей системе `read()` читает разное количество байт; оно или равно сумме размеров f1+f2, или размеру только f1.

Answer (score 2):

### Немного о том, как всё работает под капотом.

- **cat** работает достаточно просто: для каждого файла сначала читает его кусок в свой буфер (в пользовательском пространстве), а затем записывает его в `stdout` и так пока файл не закончится. В примитивном варианте<sup>¹</sup> это выглядит как-то так:

  ```
  while (1) {
    ssize nreads = read (fd, buff, BUFF_SZ);
    if (nreads<=0) {
      break;
    }
    write (fd, buff, nreads)
  }
  ```

  Типовой размер буфера сегодня — 128k.
- **dd** работает практически также, только размер блока, который он читает задаётся в аргументах `bs`, а также по ходу дела он отсчитывает прочитанные блоки пока не дойдёт до `count`, опять же, в примитивном варианте:

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    ssize nreads = read (fd, buff, bs);
    if (nreads<=0) {
      break;
    }
    write (fd, buff, nreads)
  }
  ```
- Как уже сказали в других ответах, важный аспект системного вызова [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) в том, что он может вернуть меньшее количество байт, чем было запрошено.
- Важно также, что сама *труба* (*канал*, [*pipe*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), `|`) содержит буфер в пространстве ядра (размером 64k на пост-x86 и современных ядрах). При записи в трубу данные копируются в этот буфер, а если его недостаточно, то процесс, пытающийся в неё записать приостанавливается и вызов [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) не возвращается пока кто-то не начнёт читать из трубы. Аналогично, если в буфере пусто, то процесс, пытающийся читать, приостанавливается пока кто-то не напишет в трубу.

### Что же происходит?

И так, при вызове `cat f1 f2 | dd bs=12582912 count=1`

`cat` производит примерно следующую последовательность вызовов:

```
cat: f1_sz = read (f1_fd, buf, 128*1024); // 2048
cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f1_sz);  // ok
cat: f2_sz = read (f2_fd, buf, 128*1024); // 115424
cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f2_sz);  // block
```

При этом первый `write` не должен блокировать процесс т.к.  `cat` будет гарантированно заблокирован только на втором  т.к. первый вполне

При этом `dd` **параллельно** с этим производит следующие действия:

```
dd : rd_sz = read (pipefd, buf, bs); // (?) block
dd :         write (1 /*stdout*/, buf, rd_sz);
```

т.к. `count` равен `1`, то большо одного чтения не произойдёт.

Повторяясь ещё раз, `cat` и `dd` работают *параллельно*, а это слово просто напрашивается на то, чтобы между процессами возникло состояние гонки, так что есть несколько возможных порядков в котором будут происходить вызовы связанные с трубой:

1. `dd` всех обогнал:

   ```
   dd : rd_sz = read (pipefd, buf, bs);     // block
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f1_sz); // ok
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f2_sz); // error
   ```

   В этом случае `dd` заблокируется на `read ()` и будет ждать, пока в трубу не придут хоть какие-то данные. На первом вызове `write()` от `cat`'а ядро напрямую скопирует данные из буфера одного процесса в буфер другого и разблокирует `dd`. После чего он запишет полученный буфер в `stdout`, отчитается о прочитанных `2048`-ми байтах и завершится.
2. `dd` успел вызваться между двумя вызовами `cat`'а:

   ```
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f1_sz); // ok
   dd : rd_sz = read (pipefd, buf, bs);     // ok
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f2_sz); // error
   ```

   `cat` запишет содержимое `f1` в буфер трубы и продолжит дальше заниматься своей работой, затем `dd` прочитает его из буфера и завершится с тем же результатом, что и в предыдущий раз.
3. `cat` успел быстрее:

   ```
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f1_sz); // ok
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, f2_sz); // block
   dd : rd_sz = read (pipefd, buf, bs);     // ok
   ```

   `cat` снова запишет содержимое `f1` в буфер трубы, а затем попытается записать содержимое `f2`, но т.к. размера буфера на это не хватит, то он заблокируется пока `dd` не начнёт читать. Когда это случится, то `dd` получит оба буфера: и буфер ядра и буфер ожидающего процесса. В итоге будет прочитано все `117472` байт.
4. На однопроцессорной (или просто слегка загруженной) системе, где реальной параллельности работы `cat` и `dd` нет, есть ещё один интересный вариант: что-то среднее между *1* и *3* случаем (интереса ради можно считать, что файлы передаваемые `cat`'у много больше 128k):

   ```
   dd :       → read (pipefd, buf, bs);      // block
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, BUF_SZ); // ok
   cat:         write (pipefd, buf, BUF_SZ); // ok
   cat: // ...
   cat: // У cat кончается время
   dd : rd_sz = read (/*...*/) → n*BUF_SZ;   // returns
   ```

   Т.е. `dd` начинает чтение. и блокируется на вызове `read()`, затем процессорное время передаётся `cat`'у и он за отведённый ему *промежуток времени* (*time slice*) успевает с помощью `write()` набить буфер столько, сколько успеет (подразумевая, что файл уже находится в кеше и блокироваться на чтение с диска ему не нужно). После чего управление передаётся `dd` и только тогда происходит возврат из `read()`.

### Что делать?

Если частичное чтение происходит на каком-то блоке кроме последнего (в частности, в данном случае, если изменить `count` на `2`), то он заботливо предупреждает

```
dd: warning: partial read (2048 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
```

т.е. чтобы заставить `dd` изменить алгоритм так, чтобы обрабатывать не полностью прочитанные за один вызов блоки нужно всего лишь добавить `iflag=fullblock`:

```
./script.sh | dd bs=12582912 count=1 iflag=fullblock
```

Подробности см. в [`man dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html).

---

> Каково происхождение загадочных чисел 2048 и 117472?

Очевидно, что это размеры файлов *f1* и *f1+f2* cоответственно.

---

<sup>¹ Здесь и далее вся обработка ошибок, дополнительных флагов и необычных ситуаций опущена ради упрощения.</sup>

Comment: Можно ли из этого сделать вывод, что процесс, расположенный справа от трубы `|` не может прочитать "за раз" больше чем размер буфера этой трубы, т.е. 64Кб? Если да, то как вы объясните следующие выводы для файла `truncate -s 888888888`: `cat a1 | dd bs=129348341 count=1`, которые для разных запусков выдают разные числа, различные на порядок: `13107200 bytes (13 MB, 12 MiB) copied, 0.311852 s, 42.0 MB/s`; `4587520 bytes (4.6 MB, 4.4 MiB) copied, 0.057983 s, 79.1 MB/s`; `262144 bytes (262 kB, 256 KiB) copied, 0.0376964 s, 7.0 MB/s`; `131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.011839 s, 11.1 MB/s`?

Comment: Если же нет, то и в таком случае, пожалуйста, объясните ограничивающее действие этих буферов.

Comment: @edem, нет, как описано в случае (3) если размера буфера трубы в ядре не хватает, то процесс, пытающийся в неё записать блокируется, а при чтении данные копируются напрямую из буфера пишущего процесса в буфер читающего....  что происходит в твоём случае — расписал подробно в (4); заметь, что все числа кратны буферу чтения `cat`'а (128k)...

Comment: У меня не "однопроцессорный" и не "сильнозагруженный" случай. 4 ядра.

Comment: @edem, сценарий тот же, но почему так происходит в конкретном случае я точно сказать не могу — у меня ни как не получалось это воспроизвести... возможно в новых (старых) ядрах несколько отличается алгоритм планировщика... возможно просто планировщик так настроен, что из оболочки из которой ты запускаешь всё работает только на одном ядре... возможно ядро как-то неправильно собрано... возможно ты что-то ещё не договариваешь... возможно я чего-то ещё не знаю...

Comment: Запусти в цикле эти команды и посмотри выводы, у меня они также не с первых разов стали выдавать такие цифры, в основном не больше 350Кб.

Comment: @edem, цикл — это уже 3-4 процесса работающие параллельно: оболочка, `cat`, `dd`, а ещё эмулятор терминала, если в иксах... вот так статистически и получается, что иногда какая-нить плазма или браузер проснутся и на `dd` уже не остаётся свободного процесса... стохастические предсказания такие стохастически...

Comment: Ну можете ручками понабирать команды эти, числа одни и те же получить можно от 128Кб, до нескольких десятков Мб при чтении через `dd`. Буфер не ограничивает в этом его.

Comment: @edem, это тот случай, когда размер не имеет значения, по факту есть только два исхода: или 128k, или что-то большее и последние так или иначе куда менее вероятно... но да, соглашусь —  вероятность второго умозрительно я сильно преуменьшал...

Answer (score 0):

> Что происходит?

```
$ ./script.sh | dd bs=12582912 count=1 > something
```

dd считывает один входящий блок данных STDOUT (из ОЗУ) указанного размера.

> Почему последняя команда не выдаёт 12582912 байт?

Потому что script.sh использует три разных вызова для наполнения STDOUT, по одному для каждого считываемого файла посредством `cat` другой для `dd`, а вероятность того, что будут использованы *последовательно идущие* блоки памяти для хранения этих данных ничтожно мала. Они могут быть расположены в любой последовательности. Это можно легко увидеть на примере.

Создадим три файла 1, 2 и 3 байта соответственно.

```
truncate -s 1 a1; truncate -s 2 a2; truncate -s 3 a3
```

Прочитаем их с помощью `cat` и полученную сборную данных для эти трёх файлов (всего 6 байт: 1 + 2 + 3) передадим `dd` для обработки с размером 10 байт (должен прочитать за раз).

При первом запуске удалось лишь один байт, остальные, видимо, "далеко".

```
cat a1 a2 a3 | dd bs=10 count=1 > something
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
1 byte copied, 0.00144402 s, 0.7 kB/s
```

Во время второго запуска смогли прочитать все шесть за раз. Повезло.

```
cat a1 a2 a3 | dd bs=10 count=1 > something
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
6 bytes copied, 0.000348189 s, 17.2 kB/s
```

Ну а на третий раз в один блок попали то ли два файла `a1` и `a2` вместе, то ли один `a3`.

```
cat a1 a2 a3 | dd bs=10 count=1 > something
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
3 bytes copied, 0.000632707 s, 4.7 kB/s
```

Таким образом, то количество байт X, которое вы ожидаете прочитать за раз с помощью `dd bs=X count=1` будет равно X лишь только в том случае, когда эти X *будут расположены в одном блоке памяти*. Ну и если хватит памяти на само чтение, конечно же: имея в наличии 512Мб ОЗУ, 1Гб за раз вам не осилить.

> Каково происхождение загадочных чисел 2048 и 117472?

- 2048 — размер файла f1.
- 117472 — общий размер файлов f1 и f2 (2048 + 115424).

Ежели поменяете местами f1 и f2, то с большей вероятностью можете получить в ответе не только 2048 и сумму оных файлов, но и размер f2.

```
cat f2 f1 | dd bs=12582912 count=1 > something
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
117472 bytes (117 kB, 115 KiB) copied, 0.00181811 s, 64.6 MB/s

cat f2 f1 | dd bs=12582912 count=1 > something
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
115424 bytes (115 kB, 113 KiB) copied, 0.00124668 s, 92.6 MB/s
```

Comment: это не верное объяснение того, что происходит в системе. Нет никакой связи между пространственным размещением данных из разных файлов (они никогда не располагаются «одном блоке памяти», да и со всем остальным: оно просто устроено не так, как ты описываешь)... дело здесь исключительно в наивном алгоритме работы `dd` и в гонке по времени.

Comment: Как-то осталось непонятно, что помешало dd или каким-то механизмам ОС скопировать три 1+2+3 непоследовательных блока из stdin в один последовательный 6-байтный блок в памяти процесса dd. Да и вообще stdin это по задумке просто ничем не разделённый поток байт, почему тут блоки внезапно имеют значение?

Comment: @Fat-Zer перечитай ответ, там нет ни слова про "пространственное размещение данных из разных файлов" и "они никогда не располагаются "одном блоке памяти". Речь про STDOUT и лишь про него, про его наполнение, а сами файлы хранятся вообще на жестком диске. А простыми словами можно про "наивный алгоритм работы" и "гонку по времени", так сказать на пальцах, в виде ответа?

Comment: @edem, а что же тогда означает фраза «когда эти X будут расположены в одном блоке памяти»?.. про то как всё устроено и что я подразумевал под своими мутными формулировками — расписал...

Comment: @Fat-Zer в одном блоке памяти данных ОЗУ из STDOUT, которые успели там оказаться при чтении `cat` с целью считывания `dd` для которого это является STDIN. И спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, который вы дали.